# HTTParty.head retrieves full response for MP3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to check the health of some mp3s, so I just want to make a head request and see the response code. However when I use HTTParty.head on mp3s I'm receiving the full response.

e.g., `response = HTTParty.head("https://archive.org/download/is-los-angeles-still-a-city-of-quartz.LYaAW6.popuparchive.org/ww_2015-06-18-202413.6929.mp3")`

Using curl works as expected `curl -IL https://archive.org/download/is-los-angeles-still-a-city-of-quartz.LYaAW6.popuparchive.org/ww_2015-06-18-202413.6929.mp3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/345) the issue you're looking for on GitHub. One of the answers work (seems to be a problem with redirects):

```
HTTParty.head("https://archive.org/download/is-los-angeles-still-a-city-of-quartz.LYaAW6.popuparchive.org/ww_2015-06-18-202413.6929.mp3", follow_redirects: true, maintain_method_across_redirects: true)
```